# wordpress - how to proper set up archive page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have posttypes.php file in which i register post types

```
  <?php
add_action('init', 'lovetocreateelevationprojects_init_posttypes');
function lovetocreateelevationprojects_init_posttypes()
{
    $projects_args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'public_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'
        ),
        'has_archieve' => true
    );

    register_post_type('projects', $projects_args);
}
```

I have new post type - gallery and this post type is visible in wordpress administration panel. I created new archive-projects.php file and everything what is inside so far is:

```
<?php
echo 'its working';
```

The file seems not to be working because when i enter `http://localhost/webname/projects/` path it redirects me to index.php and i dont have *'its working'* message.

I use my own link format: `http://localhost/webname/%category%/%postname%/`

Answer (score 2):

I think every thing is  ok but `rewrite` and `query_var` correctly to be accessible from url.

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'lovetocreateelevationprojects_init_posttypes');
    function lovetocreateelevationprojects_init_posttypes()
    {
        $projects_args = array(
            'public' => true,
            'public_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => 'projects',
            'rewrite' => ['slug'=>'project'],
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports' => array(
                'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'
            ),
            'has_archive' => true
        );

        register_post_type('projects', $projects_args);
    }
```

Comment: it still redirects me to index.php. I feel like its trying to get page from wrong adress. the get request is send _http://localhost/webname/project_. When i put file named 'project' in the webname directory it works. But im not sure it supposed to be done this way. My archive-projects file is inside theme.

Comment: what you get in this url ? `localhost/webname/?post_type=projects`

if it works correct go to `settings-> permalink` and save settings again

Comment: its loading index.php again. Saved again settings and still the same.

Comment: may i have any access for the website?